# Вывести все знаки раздела и их указатели в введенной строке

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Не выводит то, что нужно, в общем не знаю как писать(

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
     setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
     string str;
          cin >> str;
          cout << "Символы: ";
          for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
              while (str[i]){
             if (ispunct(str[i])){
                 cout << "str[" << i << "] = " << str[i] << endl;
             }
             i++;
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А что вы считаете знаками раздела? `ispunct()` проверяет только знаки пунктуации. Если вы хотите проверять ещё и пробелы и табуляции, то используйте `isspace()`. Плюс, если в вашей строке есть пробелы, то обычный `cin` не пойдёт. Нужно использовать `getline()`. А ещё не понятно, зачем вы заводите цикл `while` как только встретили нужный символ внутри `for` и этим циклом уже проходите всю оставшуюся строку, хотя всё это можно сделать с помощью `for`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    string symbs = ".,;:!?";
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    cout << "Символы: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (symbs.find(str[i]) != -1)
            cout << "str[" << i << "] = " << str[i] << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: не-а, не работает

Comment: @AlexHteppl Так а какие символы разделения вам нужны, уточните

Comment: Немного накосячил с кавычками, исправил

Comment: Вот такие:   .,;:!?

Comment: Функция `ispunct()` выдаёт больше знаков пунктуации, возможно проблема в этом. Предложенный вариант в изменённом ответе

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое!!!

Comment: Если ответ помог, пометьте его как верный (галочка слева от ответа)